# How to use textColorPrimary as background color in a style?

Tags: android, styles

I want to create a style which uses the android `textColorPrimary` as a background color.
I tried the following which does not work, the result is my layout not beeing displayed at all.

```
<style name="horizontalLine">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

How do I use textColorPrimary as background color in a style?

Comment: similar query was raised  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850597/consistent-ui-color-in-all-android-devices) Here 

Hope its helpful for you

Comment: @Ashish: not at all, the other questionaire wants to know how to set colors in general, I want to know how to use textColorPrimary as backgronud color.

Comment: You can get manually this color by doing this: `textView.getCurrentTextColor();` and get this color from a TextView which uses it. If you want to control this color use: `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>` for black for example OR `<item android:color="@color/default_text_color" />`. Tell me if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Also, one additional method: `textView.getTextColors();`.

Comment: @g00dy: for your approach I have to later set the color from Java source code, but my question is about doing it in the xml style

Comment: There's some part for the `xml` too :-) Look again at my previous comment and tell me if it doesn't work: `<item android:color="@color/default_text_color" />`.

Comment: Have you tried `@android:color/primary_text_dark` instead of `textcolorprimary` ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast: what happens to primary_text_dark if the user chooses to use a non dark theme for his android device?

Answer (score 8):

This syntax seems to work for me, when trying to use attributes:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:text="Hello"/>
```

(or)

```
<style name="MyStyle">
   <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I can change the app theme from Holo to Holo.Light and the text color will change automatically to fit.

It doesn't work when I set it as a background of a View though - Android will crash complaining that the drawable referenced is a state list that does not specify drawables (it is a [state list of colors](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/color/primary_text_holo_dark.xml)).

```
    Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
    ... 39 more
```

I am using [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) which lets me reference the resources directly, but you should get a similar problem in the native case. I don't think the primary, non-selected, non-activated (etc.) color used as a component in the state list xml is exposed through an attribute.

In any case, the text color used is dependent on the theme that you, the app developer, chooses. If you choose to use the Holo (dark) theme then your text will be a light color, and the user won't be able to affect this. You don't need to make the your line color dynamic for your app.

Comment: So, how do I use it as a background color?

Comment: @johannes, I have provided a couple of options as to how you can set it as the background colour of your style or view in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623525/1071320).

Answer (score 3):

To apply the `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` attribute as the background of a view, you have two options.

#### First Option

The first option is to define a `shape` drawable which gets its color from the `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` attribute, as follows...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

... and, assuming you've named this drawable `rectangle_shape_with_primary_text_color.xml` and placed it in your application's `res/drawable` folder, you can set it as the background of your style as follows...

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/rectangle_shape_with_primary_text_color</item>
```

... or set it as the background of your view directly, as follows...

```
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape_with_primary_text_color"
```

#### Second option

The second option is to set the `backgroundTint` property of your style or view.

You can set the `backgroundTint` property of your style as follows:

```
<style name="horizontalLine">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Or you can set the `backgroundTint` property of your view directly as follows:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
```

Note that the exact value of the `background` property with this approach is not important but it must be set and it cannot be set to `@null` or `@android:color/transparent`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message I get for this is:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

Doing a little digging, the specs say the `background` attribute should support either a colour, or reference to a drawable resource:

... Looking at the resource you're referencing, it *is* a `StateListDrawable`.

```
platforms/android-17/data/res/color/primary_text_dark.xml

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark_inverse"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark"/> <!-- not selected -->
</selector>
```

However, the docs for StateListDrawable also explicitly say the `drawable` attribute must be defined for `item` elements:

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

<item>
    Defines a drawable to use during certain states, as described by its attributes. Must be a child of a <selector> element.

    attributes:

    android:drawable
        Drawable resource. Required. Reference to a drawable resource.
```

... which isn't the case for the case for `primary_text_dark.xml`. So, it's not working because the drawable you're referencing doesn't seem to conform to the spec.

I think the workaround is to reference the colour that's used in `primary_text_dark` for the default state: `bright_foreground_dark`. Seeing as that's not public, you need to go directly to the one it references, which is:

```
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to use native android primary text color.

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
```