# Setting a theme for my custom DialogPreference?

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I have a custom `DialogPreference` that I use for a `SeekBar`. I override `style="@style/Theme.Putio.Dialog"` and inflate the layout from XML.

The problem is, the resulting dialog uses the default Android dialog style, and I want it to use mine.

Where do I tell it to use my dialog? I'll post code if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: DialogPreference color/style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681398/android-dialogpreference-color-style)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31858497/1317086 - it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom styles for your Dialog inside the styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialogback</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item></style>
```

And to use following code while creating the Dialog.

```
final Dialog CustomDialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: I use this in another part of my application and it works fine. But this time I'm using a DialogPreference, where you don't explicitly create the dialog (afaik).