# Custom DialogPreference & TextView color/theme

Tags: android, layout, colors, dialog, textview

I create the custom DialogPreference with this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class DialogPref extends DialogPreference {

    public DialogPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.my_dialog);
    }
}
```

And with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And when I compile this it shown to me the valid dialog but the TextView on this dialog is black on dark background. So, How to change the TextView color with Dialog theme but not manually in layout? Thanx

Comment: While I'm adding "`android:textColor="@android:color/white"`" to the TextView, but I think it is not valid way. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31858497/1317086 - it looks like your problem can be solved using theme attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can define a general Theme and set this Theme to the Dialog, passing it through the constructor.

```
  public DialogPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs,R.style.DialogTheme);

    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.my_layout);
}
```

How to define a Theme : [Android Styles and Themes - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)